# Sqoop Incremental Import multiple columns in check-column

Tags: sqoop

How to import the Incremental data from Oracle based on multiple columns?

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:ip/dbname --username sqoop --password sqoop \
--query 'SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE $CONDITIONS' \
--check-column column1,column2 \
--incremental lastmodified \
--last-value "2010-05-22 01:01:01" \
-fields-terminated-by \| \
--target-dir /directoryname` --split-by id -m 1
```

When I use this, column2 is not recognized and it's throwing an error. Need help on this.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what Sqoop Incremental should do with the two columns...

You want to grab all rows where column1 is larger than last-value? column2? whichever is larger? whichever is smaller?

Because sqoop has no idea how you want to combine them, it will not support multiple columns.

You can, however, combine them yourself and use a function as --check-column.

For example:
--check-column nvl(column1,column2)
or
--check-column greatest(column1,column2)

Answer (score 0):

--check-column does not support sql function,
you can create a view, just like

```html
create view <view_name> as (
  col2,
  col2,
  col1+col2 as col3
)
```