# How to take updated records along with incremental import from RDBMS table to a Hive table?

Tags: shell, hadoop, hive, sqoop

Im working with Sqoop incremental import by taking the data everyday into my hive table. I have the following scenario:
I have an RDBMS table: empdata with columns

```
id  name    city
1   Sid     Amsterdam
2   Bob     Delhi
3   Sun     Dubai
4   Rob     London
```

I am importing the data into Hive, using Sqoop incremental import through a cron job which shell script to do the work.

```
#!/bin/bash
DATE=$(date +"%d-%m-%y")
while IFS=":" read -r server dbname tablename; do
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://$server/$dbname --table $tablename --username root --password cloudera --hive-import --hive-table dynpart --hive-partition-key 'thisday' --hive-partition-value $DATE --target-dir '/user/hive/newimp5' --incremental-append --check-column id --last-value $(hive -e "select max(id) from $tablename");
done</home/cloudera/Desktop/MyScripts/tables.txt
```

The above script for incremental load is working fine. But now I have another requirement, which is to check if there are any updates to previous records. Like if the record:
`1 Rob London is updated to 1 Rob NewYork` I need to take that updated record(s) along with the incremental import but only the updated value should be present in Hive table so that I don't have duplicate values either. Could anyone tell me how can I accomplish it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In sqoop you can not use 2 columns in --check-column and even if you are allowed (you can combine 2 fields in --check-column see ex : [Sqoop Incremental Import multiple columns in check-column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23532525/sqoop-incremental-import-multiple-columns-in-check-column/36573095)) then also you are not sure if the city will have the higher or lower value next time so you can not really use city field in check column . now you have following options :

1) in your RDBMS create a new table where you have another field of type timestamp and this will be auto incremented so that every time you have any update or insert it has the current time stamp. and then after incremental append you again import this table using incremental lastmodified ...--check-column ts_field -- last-value  also use "--merge-key id" in sqoop import so that  it can merge the updates on the basis of id.

2)  a) first run your sqoop import with --check-cloumn id --incremental append last value  
   b) then run the sqoop import again without using --incremental and with target dir as some temporary folder
   c) then using sqoop merge merge the dataset(target-dir in step a.  and b ) where new data will be in target dir of step a onto tar dir of step b and --merge key will be "id".

Please let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: So there should be two sqoop commands, one for normal incremental import and another one like below:
'sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://server/dbname --table tablename --username root --password cloudera --hive-import --hive-table dynpart --hive-partition-key 'thisday' --hive-partition-value DATE --target-dir '/user/hive/newimp5' --incremental-append --check-column timestampcolumn --last-modified 'sometimestamp' --merge-key id '

Comment: Will sqoop 'mergey-key' automatically replace only those old matching records with new records in the Hive table if you use it along with the incremental import ?

Comment: also i am not sure if following would work..but you can check and let me know... after running incremental (as your sqoop command in sqoop) run another sqoop import and dont use incremental and in the same sqoop command use the same folder as target-dir and give --append and --merge-key id it should work.

Comment: or if you want to go with the second approach from my last reply.. you should first run you normal incremental like below(copeid from your question )  
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://$server/$dbname --table $tablename --username root --password cloudera --hive-import --hive-table dynpart --hive-partition-key 'thisday' --hive-partition-value $DATE --target-dir '/user/hive/newimp5' --incremental-append --check-column id --last-value $(hive -e "select max(id) from $tablename");
and then run the normal import without incremental in new folder and then sqoop merge

Comment: and if you have timestamp avalaible in your table you can simplay write a sqoop job and use incremental lastmodified --check-column ts_field and use the same folder as target everytime you run this job but make sure to have --append and --merger-key id

Comment: If I have the data in a directory/location: 'directory-a' on top of which I have a HIVE table built, and I get the sqoop import with last-modified into a new directory 'directory-b', Can I merge directory-a and directory-b and put the target directory as 'directory-a' which is my Hive table's directory using sqoop merge command. 
Also I didn't understand the second point from your answer. Would you care explaining it a bit more..